# Erro de sintaxe SQL SUM()

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

Uma tabela de produtos (`tbl_prods`) que possui entre outros campo o preço de cada produto o tipo dos produtos e  a data da transação (`dt_trns`). Os tipos podem ser `typ1`, `typ3` ou `typ3`.

Eu quero uma query que retorne a soma dos preços dos produtos vendidos para um determinado usuário no ano de 2016 e no mês de dez, sendo que se o produto for do tipo 2 (typ2) deve ter 40% de desconto.

Isso é o que tenho mas não está dando certo:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(prodtype='typ2',price*0.6,price)) FROM tbl_prods WHERE userId=123 AND YEAR(dt_trns)=2016 AND MONTH(dt_trns)=12;
```

Resultado = `“You have an error in your SQL syntax; …”`

Onde estou errando?

Comment: Não seria este "." no final "...12."?

Comment: não  existe o ponto. Foi um ponto paragrafo eu vou retirar.

Comment: Você esta executando essa `query` no seu programa ou esta executando em algum gerenciador de banco de dados?

Comment: Estou no workbench

Comment: achei, tava faltando aspas.  YEAR(dt_trns)='2016' AND MONTH(dt_trns)='12'

Answer (score 0):

Faltou um AS nome_de_retorno. O correto seria:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(prodtype='typ2',price*0.6,price)) as soma FROM tbl_prods WHERE userId=123 AND YEAR(dt_trns)=2016 AND MONTH(dt_trns)=12;
```